# Convert int to date in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column which is called `duration_stay(int)` and a column `movedate(dateime)`,Now what I want to do is `add duration_stay` to `movedate` so I can get the `toDate`.Can someone Help me out?

this is something I tried

```
Select DateADD(d,duration_stay,movedate) as toDate from Table_name;
```

I am not getting the result

**Expected Output**

```
 duration_stay    movedate        todate

 1                2013-08-08       2013-08-09
```

Comment: Is the duration in day, or hours/ minutes?

Comment: What does the "int" represent?

Comment: `To_Date` isn't a built in function in SQL Server - so either its a UDF that we have no idea what the definition is or you're receiving an error message when you are "not getting the result". If you're getting an error message, please *include* it in your question.

Comment: duration_stay is the number of days which I am storing in int datatype

Comment: What *does* what you have give you? You say it isn't the expected result, but what does it say?

Comment: it returns nothing..its empty,inspite of data being there in the table

Comment: DateAdd will return null if duration_stay is null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,duration_stay,movedate) AS toDate FROM Table_name;
```

Comment: movedate is datetime and duration_stay is int column, then it will work well. I dont know what is your real problem...

Comment: thank you it worked..like a fool i was entering the wrong empid! thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @duration_stay int = 1 
DECLARE @movedate datetime = GETDATE()

SELECT @duration_stay , Convert(varchar, @movedate, 107) , Convert(varchar, DateADD(d, @duration_stay, @movedate), 107) as toDate
```